# Progress bar with an image

Tags: html, progress-bar, progress

I wanted to know if it is possible to style the Progress bar introduced by HTML5 in such a way that I can put an image in it.
To be more concrete, let's imagine a car ride from a city to another. I want to display the evolution of the car in a progress bar.

```
<progress id='movingbar' value="50" max="200"></progress>
```

But to be more stylish, I want this progress bar to display an image of a car at the position of the "value".

I've not found any website discussing about it.
If it's not possible to do it using HTML5 tag, then is it possible by another way ?

Thanks beforehand

Comment: It's always possible another way.

Comment: It will most likely be a case of just attaching an <img> floated right inside the progress bar div.  That way you have your bar, and on the right a little image of a car....if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page here changes the background images of the progress bar.

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/

Comment: Thanks for this link. It is very useful. However, implementing a good-looking and responsive solution appears to be quite hard according to my CSS level.

Comment: There are easier solutions in jqueryUI. http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#indeterminate

Comment: I've already seen it but for a car application, a so simple progressBar does not fit my requirements

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar where I wanted a progress bar with text under it. The text followed the progress bar. This way you could see the task that was being complete.

You can accomplish this be creating a . The keep is to use

```
width: [percentage of complete]%;
align: right;
```

You can continue to update the width with whatever percentage complete you want. You can also change the car image at specific points. This will require a lot of hard coding, but it is possible. Good Luck

Comment: The problem is that I want the image to be on the progress bar. I don't want it to be above or below.